# ASP.NET Login Control is redirecting to default.aspx even when the destinationpageurl is not set

Tags: asp.net, authentication

We have a login control on a page named login.aspx which is set as the start page of the website. Once the user logs in, it is redirecting to default.aspx although our destinationpageurl is not set to any value.

If we set the destinationpageurl to somepage.aspx, it is working redirecting properly, but why is it redirecting to default.aspx by default, if the destinationpageurl is not set.

Thanks for any help,
Animesh

Comment: By default, Default.aspx is the default page in a website.

Answer (score 3):

The [defaultUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.defaulturl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) under authentication tag in web.config the reason for automatic redirection to default.aspx.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms 
  name="401kApp" 
  loginUrl="/login.aspx"
  cookieless="AutoDetect"
  **defaultUrl="myCustomLogin.aspx">**
  <credentials passwordFormat = "SHA1">   
     <user name="UserName" 
     password="07B7F3EE06F278DB966BE960E7CBBD103DF30CA6"/>
  </credentials>   
  </forms>
```

Change this if you want to redirect to some other page instead of default.aspx .

Answer (score 1):

Is it just redirecting to / and it's actually IIS which is serving default.aspx, based on the default document settings?

Answer (score 0):

Redirection is required to set cookies. To write anything in cookie (session or anything) an action is needed to performed. Simlest action is redircetion.
While performing redirection it writes authentication information.